# How to show Images in Angular if condition is met

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an API call which returns back a number. If the number is positive show a green a image [image]and if a button is negative show red[image] I want a red image to show.

If I try this the image loops multiple time instead of a single time, How can I achieve this?

This is what I have

```
 <td class="warning" [ngStyle]="{'background-image' : (reports.response_rate_7day_change > 0) ? getIncrease():  getDecrease() }"></td>
```

My functions to fetch the images from local storage

```
 getIncrease()
  {
    return "url('assets/images/increase.png')";
  }

  getDecrease()
  {
    return "url('assets/images/decrease.png')";
  }
```

when I run the code and the value returned is negative it show the image below, am not sure what am doing wrong
[image]

Comment: I would rather create proper CSS markup with .increse .decrese classes and switch those.

Comment: Yeah I think using ngClass would be better too. An other way to do it can be using  `img` tag with *ngIf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has nothing to do with angular but your CSS try this:

```
 <td class="warning" [ngStyle]="{'background-image' : (reports.response_rate_7day_change > 0) ? getIncrease():  getDecrease() }"
style="background-repeat: no-repeat"></td>
```